# c# write xml muitiable atrrtibutes

Tags: c#, xml

I am creating xml file with c#, The xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project Title="old one" 
         Version="1.5.1.0" 
         Author="" 
         EmphasisColor1Label="" 
         EmphasisColor1="#000000" 
         EmphasisStyle1="---" >
</Project>
```

my c# code is:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
XmlDeclaration decl = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null);
doc.AppendChild(decl);
XmlElement ChatMapper = doc.CreateElement("Project");  
doc.AppendChild(ChatMapper);
XmlNode xmldocSelect = doc.SelectSingleNode("Project");
//Crteate Attribute

XmlAttribute attra = doc.CreateAttribute("Title");
attra.Value ="old one";
xmldocSelect.Attributes.Append(attra);

XmlAttribute attrb = doc.CreateAttribute("Version");
attrb.Value ="1.5.1.0";
xmldocSelect.Attributes.Append(attrb);

XmlAttribute attrc = doc.CreateAttribute("EmphasisColor1Label");
attrc.Value ="";
xmldocSelect.Attributes.Append(attrc);

XmlAttribute attrd = doc.CreateAttribute("EmphasisColor1");
attrd.Value ="#000000";
xmldocSelect.Attributes.Append(attrd);

XmlAttribute attre = doc.CreateAttribute("EmphasisStyle1");
attre.Value ="---";
xmldocSelect.Attributes.Append(attre);
```

That is not smart and too long, anyone knows how to make it shorter?

Comment: You better ask this question here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Put the name and value of the attributes in a Dictionary. Pass that to method with a reference to doc, loop through adding them, would be one way...

Comment: You could always try serialising a class.http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/483055/XML-Serialization-and-Deserialization-Part

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use System.Xml.Linq namespace to create xml. Code snippet in C#:

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument(
    new XElement("Project ",
        new XAttribute("Title", "old one"),
        new XAttribute("Version", "1.5.1.0"),
        new XAttribute("Author", ""),
        new XAttribute("EmphasisColor1Label", ""),
        new XAttribute("EmphasisColor1", "#000000"),
        new XAttribute("EmphasisStyle1", "")
    )
);
doc.Save("Project.xml");
```

Comment: If do not use linq, how show should I write the code?

Comment: Or you can create object and deserialize to xml .Somethin like this.  http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/generate-xml-from-object-in-C-Sharp/

Answer (score 1):

**Using LINQ**:-

```
using System.Xml.Linq;


var xml =
        new XElement("Project",
             new XAttribute("Title", "old one"),
             new XAttribute("Version", "1.5.1.0"),
             new XAttribute("Author", ""),
             new XAttribute("EmphasisColor1Label", ""),
             new XAttribute("EmphasisColor1", "#000000"),
             new XAttribute("EmphasisStyle1", "---")
        );

        xml.Save("Project.xml");
```

Answer (score 1):

**WITHOUT LINQ:-**

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlDeclaration decl = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null);
        doc.AppendChild(decl);
        XmlElement ChatMapper = doc.CreateElement("Project");

        ChatMapper.SetAttribute("Title", "old one");
        ChatMapper.SetAttribute("Version", "1.5.1.0");
        ChatMapper.SetAttribute("EmphasisColor1", "#000000");
        ChatMapper.SetAttribute("EmphasisStyle1", "---");

        doc.AppendChild(ChatMapper);

        doc.Save("project.xml");
```